# how to use different IP address for development and production with react and axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am building an app using react & django rest framework.I can access all of data via axios url (127.0.0.1:8000). But when i deploy it to azure for production then the axios ip needs to change by azure container ip for requesting to the url. What is the best way to do this for production?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [environment variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) by creating a `.env` file. You can have a `.env.development` file for development and a `.env.production` file for production.

When you are developing on your machine with `npm start` or `yarn start`, it will use the `.env.development` file in your application.

Note: You need to restart the development server after changing .env files for your changes to take effect during development.

When you build for production with `npm build` or `yarn build`, it will use the `.env.production` file.

**.env.development**

```
REACT_APP_AXIOS_URL="127.0.0.1:8000"
```

**.env.production**

```
REACT_APP_AXIOS_URL="http://yourapi.com"
```

Then your application code only needs to reference these variables through `process.env`.

```js
axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_AXIOS_URL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `config` for this purpose. It will create multiple configuration files which are loaded according to the application environment. In your scenario, you need to install `config` using:

```
npm i config
```

After that create a `config` folder in your project root. Create two files as `default.json` and `production.json`. Now you can create the `JSON` file like this with different value for both files/environments:

```
{
  serverURL: "localhost:3000"
}
```

And then use variable like:

```
const config = require('config').default;

const url = config.get('serverURL');
```

Pass this `url` variable to `axios` while requesting. And it will automatically choose the `IP` depending on the environment set. When you create a `react.js` app build, it sets the environment to production. Hope this will help you.